# Connect using Bluetooth to different devices using the same UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, sdp

I am trying to create a bluetooth connection between multiple devices. I am using one device to listen for incoming connections, using the following code:

listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, my_UUID);

My question is, can I use the same UUID to create more than one connection? I understand from the Android documentation that the bluetooth API creates a SDP-entry consisting of the UUID and the channel number. If this is correct, I cannot create two simultaneous connection using the same channel number, can I?

Comment: Nobody has any suggestions :(